# How to export multiple objects to one spreadsheet?

Tags: powershell, export-to-excel

I'm putting together a table with device details, and another table that's a 'quote' to be issued to a client. I have most of it working, I could export each table individually to a different file but I want to combine them into the same file and sheet, preferably with a blank row or two between them. I'll spare you reading through all of the code but can supply amplifying information if necessary. Really, the bit I'm struggling with is this:

```
$excelParams = @{
    Path = $excelPath
    WorksheetName = "PCs"
    Show = $true
    Verbose = $true
}
$excel =  $deviceListSorted, $quoteItems | Export-Excel @excelParams -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -FreezeFirstColumn -PassThru
```

When I use this line all I get in the spreadsheet is the object in $deviceListSorted, but I don't get any error.

I am doing some data validation and formatting later in the script after this export line, and even that stuff comes through, but the data inside $quoteItems doesn't make it across.

I have tried separating them out into two lines but that doesn't work either. For example

```
$excel =  $deviceListSorted | Export-Excel @excelParams -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -FreezeFirstColumn -PassThru
$excelPackage =  $quoteItems | Export-Excel @excelParams -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -FreezeFirstColumn -PassThru
```

This brings across only the $quoteItems table

Answer (score -1):

To merge your $deviceListSorted and $quoteItems into the same Excel file and worksheet, you will need to do a bit more than just piping them into Export-Excel. The Export-Excel cmdlet, by default, does not append data to an existing worksheet but overwrites it. We'll need to handle this in a step-by-step manner.

First, I will outline the steps in pseudocode, and then I'll provide the full PowerShell script.

Pseudocode
Prepare Excel File: Create an Excel file with the required worksheet if it doesn't exist.
Export First Table: Export $deviceListSorted to the Excel file.
Determine Starting Row for Second Table: Find the next empty row after the last row of the first table.
Export Second Table: Export $quoteItems to the Excel file, starting from the determined row.
Formatting: Apply any additional formatting or data validation as needed.
PowerShell Script

```
# Import the required module
Import-Module ImportExcel

# Parameters for Excel export
$excelPath = "Path\To\Your\ExcelFile.xlsx"
$worksheetName = "PCs"

# Export the first table
$deviceListSorted | Export-Excel -Path $excelPath -WorksheetName $worksheetName -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -FreezeFirstColumn

# Calculate the starting row for the second table
$excel = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $excelPath
$worksheet = $excel.Workbook.Worksheets[$worksheetName]
$nextRow = ($worksheet.Dimension.End.Row + 3) # Adding 2 blank rows

# Export the second table
$quoteItems | Export-Excel -Path $excelPath -WorksheetName $worksheetName -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -FreezeFirstColumn -StartRow $nextRow -Append

# Save and close the Excel package
Close-ExcelPackage $excel
```

This script will first export $deviceListSorted to the specified worksheet. Then, it calculates the starting row for the second table ($quoteItems) by finding the last used row of the worksheet and adding a couple of rows for spacing. Finally, $quoteItems is appended to the same worksheet, starting from the calculated row.

Make sure you have the ImportExcel module installed in PowerShell, as this script relies on it for the Excel operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy